# Detect and plot all blobs larger than 100 pixel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, computer-vision

I'm working on a code to detect blobs in an image using [bwconncomp](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html). The code now plots the biggest blob in white (section below); how do you suggest to modify it so to plot the blobs with more than 100 pixels? Thanks.

Here's the code section dealing with the blob detection and plotting:

```
CC = bwconncomp(Iobr);
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList)
[biggest,idx] = max(numPixels);
Iobr(CC.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 255;
figure, imshow(Iobr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1** No-loop `bwlabel` based -

```
threshold = 100;
[L,num] = bwlabel( Iobr );
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));
B1 = bsxfun(@eq,L,permute(find(counts>threshold),[1 3 2]));
Iobr = sum(B1,3)>0;
figure, imshow(Iobr);
```

---

**Approach #2** `bwconncomp` based -

```
threshold = 100;
CC = bwconncomp(Iobr);
count_pixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
for k = 1:numel(count_pixels)
    if count_pixels(k)<=threshold
        Iobr(CC.PixelIdxList{k}) = 0;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar! When I plot 'Iobr' I don't see any change with respect to the previous image... do you know how could I plot the big blobs only?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you dont have a working example, however since you are dealing with BW images, regionprops should work:

```
BW = imread('coins.png');

% convert to BW
BW2 = BW > 80;

figure
imshow(BW2)

% properties
thresh = 2500; % Threshold of 2500 px
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW2);
props = regionprops(L, 'Area');
sel_idx = find([props.Area] > thresh);

hold all
for n = 1:length(sel_idx)
    plot(B{sel_idx(n)}(:,2), B{sel_idx(n)}(:,1), 'r')
end
```